# Scale Azure container app based on memory

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

Is it possible to scale azure container app based on memory consuption?
Docs says it is possible via custom rule, but i only see this under custom option:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

[image: scale configuration for memory based scaling]

in this example:

`type: utilization` means you want to scale based on usage percentage of the requested amount. so

```yaml
type: utilization
value: 70
```

means to scale until the average utilization across instances is below 70%.

you can also do

```yaml
type: averageValue
value: 1Gi
```

means to scale until the average usage across instances is below 1 gigabyte.

Comment: thank you, pretty much very simple, but yet i didn't find this kind information anywhere.
just to be clear for this:
type: utilization
value: 70
it will scale down if value drops bellow 70?
Currently i have 3 replicas but i put very low utilization to 10% just to see if it works :)

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that it's the average utilization. If you have 3 replicas running at 40%, 60%, 90%, your average utilization is (50+60+90)/3 = 63% and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To me looks like need to use KEDA memory scaler in container app

https://keda.sh/docs/2.12/scalers/memory/